# how to handle click event in Xamarin google map component for ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, dictionary, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am using xamarin googel map component to develop google map application in iOS. When user touches the map I want to get the location of the map that user touches. any idea.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapView has a tapped event, as well as multiple Touches* events

```
mapView.Tapped += delegate(object sender, GMSCoordEventArgs e) {
  Console.WriteLine("tapped at " + e.Coordinate.Latitude + "," + e.Coordinate.Longitude);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### GoogleMap : Marker click event with and without ClusterManager

For Xamarin.iOS , Google Map will use TappedMarker event. It might be used in three different ways.

---

> **First way of implementation:**

---

You can directly use *MapView Delegate* event *didTapMarker* . It will work along with *GMUClusterManager* such as

```
    [Export("mapView:didTapMarker:")]
    public bool TappedMarker(MapView mapView, Marker marker)
    {
        var id = marker.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(id);

        return true;
    }
```

---

> **Second way of implementation:**

---

For your GoogleMap, we can directly use *TappedMarker* method

```
    this.GMapView.TappedMarker = (map, marker) =>
    {
        var id = marker.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(id);

        return true;
    }
```

---

> **Third way of implementation:**

---

For your GoogleMap , you can use your own custom method for TappedMarker event.

```
    this.GMapView.TappedMarker = markerClicked;
```

Definition of markerClicked is here

```
    bool markerClicked(MapView map, Marker marker)
    {
        var id = marker.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(id);

        return true;
    }
```