# Xamarin Forms and maps - getting coords on map tap, creating routes?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use the latest version of Xamarin Forms for my application. This app has a tense integration with maps. Android and iOS are two supported platforms.

Right now I'm able to implement two things:

1. Centering map on any position when I have coordinates
2. Adding custom markers (pins)

The following functions are still needed (in order of importance):

1. Getting coordinates on map tap event
2. Getting coordinates in response for some search string with address
3. Routing between two points(drawing the route line)
4. Calculating time / distance between two points

I'm new to Xamarin, I checked the Xamarin Forms Maps API and as I see there's no way to implement these 4 points with it.

Am I right?
Is there any alternative Xamarin Forms packages for it?
Can I implement any of these features using native Xamarin map controls for Android / iOS?

Any info or examples are highly appreciated! 
Searching and browsing forums didn't help. I found some solutions for Google Maps API with examples in Java, but I have no idea how to implement it in Xamarin. Since a big part of application is already implemented in Xamarin and I'm used to C# I don't want to change the platform.

Comment: About your issue with "Getting coordinates on map tap event". Seems like this answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838462/how-to-handle-click-event-in-xamarin-google-map-component-for-ios

Answer (score 4):

You will need to look up the native iOS and Android implementations to do the work but you should use dependency injection from your SAP or PCL to call to the native implementations for what you need.

*Note - this is to provide a general outline of how to go about this it is not a copy paste implementation. Open map is not implemented nor are the instructions of how or when to grab the coordinates in the shared code.

Example

In shared code -

```
interface IMapping
{
    public OpenMap(); 
    public Model<GeoPoint>GetLastTouchCoordinates();         
}
```

In Android project -

```
//For use with Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService will not be necessary with other IoC containers if not using forms look up Tiny IoC, Unity or one of the other DI containers
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(YourNameSpace.Droid.YourClass))] 

public class GoogleMap : FragmentActivity, IMapping, IOnMapClickListener

{
 private GoogleMap mMap;
 private Point lastClickedPoint;

protected void OnCreate()
{
    base.OnCreate();
    setContentView(some map fragment layout)

    //set the map touch listener
}

private void handletouch()// implementation of IOnMapClickListener Interface
{
    //google how to get the coordinates in android on a map touch
    lastClickedPoint = new Point();
    lastClickedPoint.lat = args.lat;
    lastClickedPoint.long = args.long;
}

private Model<GeoPoint> GetLastTouchCoordinates()
{
    if(lastclickedPoint != null)
    {
    Model<Geopoint> gp = new Model<Geopoint>();
    gp.latitude = p.latitude;
    gp.longitude = p.longitude;
    return gp;
    }
    else
    {
      return Point with some indication that you have no point
    }

}
}
```

In Shared Code --

Now to use it simply write something like this

```
DependencyService.Get<IMapping>.OpenMap()
DependencyService.Get<IMapping>.GetLastTouchCoordinates()
```

Link to more details about Dependency Injection in cross platform code
http://adventuresinxamarinforms.com/2014/11/17/creating-a-xamarin-forms-application-part-4-dependency-injection/